# Is there something like @ObservedObject that doesn't involve creating a new class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a problem like [this one](https://forums.swift.org/t/im-so-confused-why-state-var-inside-a-view-do-not-change-when-you-call-a-method-on-this-view-from-some-outer-view/31944), but `@Binding` doesn't seem like a good solution for it. I have a view that has child views, which have their own child views, and so on. They all have a `label` attribute. If I click a button, I want to set the labels for all the views down the whole tree. The code I have is something like this:

```swift
@State var label:String = ""

func setLabel(l:String) {
    label = l
    for c in children {
        c.setLabel(l)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but if I change `label` to an `ObservedObject`, it works:

```swift
class Label: ObservableObject {
    @Published var label:String = ""
    
    func setLabel(_ s:String) {
        label = s
    }
}

@ObservedObject var label:Label = Label()
```

I don't want to create a new wrapper class each time I have to do this, though. Is there a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single source of truth, in this scenario we need only one `@State`, and then all hierarchy will be updated correctly...

Here is a demo. Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var label = "-1"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Update") { self.label = "\(Int.random(in: 0...9))" }
            Text("Main: \(label)")
            ChildDemoView(label: label)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildDemoView: View {
    let label: String
    var level = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child\(level): \(label)")
            if level < 10 {
                ChildDemoView(label: label, level: level + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```